# Programmatically create Ad-Hoc network OS X

Tags: macos, bash, networking, adhoc

How would I go about creating a wireless adhoc network with a specified SSID and password on OS X?  I tried looking at the `networksetup` man page but didn't come up with anything to accomplish this.  Is there another command I should be using?

Comment: Just an FYI if your Wi-Fi is using WPA or WPA2, computer-to-computer networks are not compatible with WPA or WPA2 protected networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any real way to do it other than to write a Swift script:

```
import Foundation
import CoreWLAN

var networkName = "foo";
var password = "bar";
var error: NSError?

let iface = CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient().interface()

let success = iface.startIBSSModeWithSSID(
    networkName.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    security: CWIBSSModeSecurity.WEP104,
    channel: 11,
    password: password as String,
    error: &error
)

if !success {
    println(error?.localizedDescription)
} else {
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().run()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In OSX 10.13, I had to modify @dan-ramos 's code to:

```
import Foundation
import CoreWLAN

let networkName = "foo"
let password = "bar"

if let iface = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface() {
    do {
        try iface.startIBSSMode(
            withSSID: networkName.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
            security: CWIBSSModeSecurity.WEP104,
            channel: 11,
            password: password as String
        )
        print("Success")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error", error)
        exit(1)
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid interface")
    exit(1)
}
```

Comment: I packaged this up for others to use: https://github.com/hildjj/adhocnet

Answer (score 0):

If you are not set on using the command line, you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/maclife_101_how_create_adhoc_network) which sets up the ad-hoc network just by using system preferences > sharing > Internet Sharing. Inside of this tab you can set up your ad-hoc network and specify an SSID, etc. Granted, this is a very rudimentary way to set it up, but it is quite user friendly, but it does not give you the way to set it up using terminal. With the `networksetup` command in the terminal, have you used `networksetup -printcommands` or `networksetup -help`? This gives additional information since there is not a man page.

I am not familiar with, but additionally have found references to using the `startHostAPModeWithSSID` command [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76372/create-airport-network-from-the-command-line) or using the `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -i` command per this [server fault entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/49732/setup-ad-hoc-wifi-from-terminal-in-os-x)

Comment: Unfortunately this does need to be done progamatically.  I have looked at networksetup commands and can't quite find anything that will work.  After doing hours of research the only option I can come up with is doing this using the `CoreWLAN` framework and writing an Objective-C/Swift script.  Even after attempting to do this I'm getting errors that almost lead me to believe there is a bug in the framework... I'll keep banging my head against the wall in the mean time

Comment: Have you tried using Automator to record a workflow and replay it and/or save it as an Apple Script?  I am working on setting up an ad-hoc network with two OS X systems now and it seems possible I will update my answer with results shortly.

Comment: i'm not going to be able to test the ad-hoc until morning, but i did find this on [server fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/49732/setup-ad-hoc-wifi-from-terminal-in-os-x) which seems to be a related question, it does not fully answer your question, but it uses the airport command in conjunction with networksetup